# Assume velocity in SHM

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

In this weeks problem set we have been given a 1D horizontal mass spring problem. The only initial conditions we have been given are: the system is released from displacement 4mm and that T = $\pi$ s. I am assuming that $A_{max}$ = 4mm and since $\omega = 2\pi/T$ then $\omega = 2Hz$.

So can I assume that at $\dot{x}(0)=0$?

Comment: In a nutshell, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one says "released", usually means "released without giving it a push". Therefore, yes.